# problem with mail attachment

Tags: asp.net

I'm having problem in  mail attachment.I'm using the fileupload control to get the path
of the file from the local machine.

It's giving the proper path but while attching the file from any folder its giving error "Invalid mail attachment".

Following is the code..

```
  protected void sndmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        objmail = new MailMessage();
        objmail.From = txt_sender.Text;
        objmail.To = txt_recipient.Text;
        objmail.Cc = txt_cc.Text;
        objmail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text;
        objmail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        objmail.Subject = txt_sub.Text;
        objmail.Body = txt_body.Text;
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";
        SmtpMail.Send(objmail);
        Response.Write("Mail send successfully...");

    }


    protected void attch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mypath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
        MessageBox.Show(mypath); 
        MailAttachment attch = new MailAttachment(mypath);

        objmail.Attachments.Add(attch);
    }
```

Can you help me work out why I'm seeing this error?

Comment: Will this code work at all? In the click event for the attachment button you refer to the email object, but in the send click event you create a new email and send that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

objmail = new MailMessage();

```
    objmail.Attachments.Add(new MailAttachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
    objmail.From = txt_sender.Text;
    objmail.To = txt_recipient.Text;
    objmail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text;
    objmail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    objmail.Subject = txt_sub.Text;
    objmail.Body = txt_body.Text;
    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "";
    SmtpMail.Send(objmail);
    Response.Write("Mail send successfully...");
```

now its working file....
using this line.....(SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "";)

thanx   for alll replies...

Answer (score 1):

The FileName property of the FileUpload control will give you the name of the file on the *client*, while the code that is creating the mail message is running on the *server*. You will need to first store the file on the server, then refer to that path when creating the mail attachment.

```
string fileNameOnServer = Path.Combine("<some writeable path on your server>", FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileNameOnServer);

// now you can user fileNameOnServer to attach the file to a mail message
objMail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileNameOnServer));
```

Answer (score 1):

When the `objmail.Attachments.Add(attch);` code is executed, the `objmail` variable is not instantiated and hence you are getting the error.

This line of code should be written in `sndmail_Click` method after `objmail = new MailMessage();`

Please mind the fact that `attch` is a local variable in `attch_Click` method and would not be accessible in the `sndmail_Click` method. You should make this variable available to both methods, hence declare along with where you've declared the `objmail` variable.

**Edit**:

However, as Fredrick has outlined in his answer you need to save the file in the server in the `attch_Click` method and in the `sndmail_Click` method add the saved file to the `objmail.Attachments` collection.

Comment: @Aarsh - You need to combine both Fredrick's & my answers. You need to save the file in the server in attch_Click method (as Fred has rightly mentioned) and in sndmail_Click, pick the saved file and add to the objmail.Attachments collection before calling SmtpMail.Send(objmail).